WorkManager stops after periodic request was triggered 3 times
I am creating an app. The app triggers an action when the phone unlocks. Since I was informed that some broadcast receivers are restricted to avoid activity from background, I created an alternative solution that starts a foreground service to check for unlock detection. To save battery, I make this unlock detection service start only at specific moments. The moments are triggered through a PeriodicWorkRequest that runs every 15 minutes, check if it's the right time, and eventually starts the foreground service if needed.
The app works, generally speaking. However, sometimes, my workmanager stops sending my planned PeriodicWorkRequests. For example, in my latest test, I create the following code, and this code triggered my doWork() 3 times at 15-minute interval. At each interval, it visualized a notification.
 PeriodicWorkRequest periodicCheckpointRequest =
        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(CheckpointWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

 workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "checkpoint_work",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                periodicCheckpointRequest
        );

I understood from the developer.android website workmanager "is the recommended task scheduler on Android for deferrable work, with a guarantee to be executed."
What are the possible reasons why the workmanager stopped? Have you got any idea how I could ensure guarantee that my task is going to be executed, and the periodic request keeps running?
